# validatecommand in Tkinter—loop validating?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is what I have so far

```
vdcm = (self.register(self.checkForInt), '%S')
roundsNumTB = Entry(self, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vdcm)
```

Then the checkForInt() function is defined as so

```
def checkForInt(self, S):
        return (S.isDigit())
```

The entry box is meant to take an even number, and a number only; not characters. If a character is inputted, it is rejected. This will only work once though. If a character is inputted, the next keystroke which is an input is not rejected.

If someone could tell me how to make it permanently check to make sure the string is a digit, and an even one at that, it would be appreciated.

This is the error message I get if it's any help

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "[py directory]", line 101, in checkForInt
    return (S.isDigit())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isDigit'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function call is `isdigit()` and not `isDigit()`, note the capitalization difference. If you want to test that the input is an integer and is even you would have to first convert the string using `int()` and test:

```
def checkForEvenInt(self, S):
    if S.isdigit():
        if int(S) % 2 is 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Keep in mind that Python is quite case-sensitive, including functions. For example, here's an iPython session:

```
In [1]: def my_func(): return True

In [2]: my_func()
Out[2]: True

In [3]: my_Func()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ac6a0a3aba88> in <module>()
----> 1 my_Func()

NameError: name 'my_Func' is not defined
```

Comment: it works because Python is case sensitive and `isdigit()` is distinct from `isDigit()`. I'll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: does that explain it? or were you confused by the modulo (%) operator?

Comment: Yeah, I do. The interpreter just dohsdknd'd (the ''d' made it a verb or something) because I didn't take into account it was case sensitive.